# Was Albus Dumbledore the member of the Wizengamot during the late 1920s?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, ministry-of-magic

[According to Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/news/everything-we-know-about-fantastic-beasts-the-crimes-of-grindelwald-so-far) the second installation of the *Fantastic Beasts* franchise is set in 1927:

> **It is set straight after the first film**
>
> The film takes place in 1927, just a few months after Newt’s first
>   adventure. So, we’re still deep in the Roaring Twenties but the
>   characters will obviously have bigger fish to fry than taking in the
>   delights of the decade.

The recently released trailer depicts an intriguing power dynamics between what is speculated Ministry of Magic officials apparating into Hogwarts grounds (but not directly into the school building) to question the Transfiguration  Professor, Albus Dumbledore in relation to his orders and connections with one Newt Scamander.

At the moment of this confrontation what were the official titles of Albus Dumbledore? Was he already a member of the Wizengamot? Do we have any information on who was the Chief Warlock of said organization at that time?

Comment: Excellent question. I'm guessing the answer is "we don't know", but I'm sure someone can narrow down sone bounds on him attaining the position.

Comment: I think he was. Although the time or duration isn't mentioned, there is some indication to that in the 5th book when Dumbledore acts as a defense for Harry's trial.

Comment: @Shreedhar we're talking about 1927, not 1995.

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes, you're right. My bad. He was asked to leave the Wizengamot in 1995 (a few weeks before Harry's trial). Maybe he was just the transfiguration professor and nothing else at that time.

Comment: Note that it would be possible for him to be on the Wizengamot without necessarily being Supreme Mugwump (just as you can be a Member of Parliament in the UK without being Prime Minister).

Comment: @TheDarkLord sure, but i think you're confusing [I.C.W.](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/international-confederation-of-wizards/) with the [wizengamot](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/wizengamot/) (an easy mistake to make as he was a member of both at same point)

Comment: @Lt.Ortega Good spot, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## We don't know but he could've been.

The only information on the matter that I could find was the following extract from Rita Skeeter.

> *Now approaching his eighteenth birthday, Dumbledore left Hogwarts in a blaze of glory - Head Boy, Prefect, Winner of the Barnabus Finkley Prize for Exceptional Spell-Casting, **British Youth Representative to the Wizengamot**, Gold Medal-Winner for Ground-Breaking Contribution to the International Alchemical Conference in Cairo.
>
>   <sub>(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 19, The Life and Lies of Albus Dumbledore).</sub>*

It looks as if Dumbledore was already on the Wizengamot when he left Hogwarts at age 17. [Pottermore](http://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/albus-dumbledore) gives his date of birth as 1881, meaning that he was a Wizengamot member by 1896 at the latest.

There's no information in canon that I'm aware of that states whether Dumbledore was a *permanent* Wizengamot member from his time at Hogwarts until his ascension to Chief Warlock. On the one hand, the title of 'Youth Representative' suggests that the role was temporary, with one Hogwarts student perhaps being elected to the position each year to gain work experience. On the other hand, if anyone was put onto the Wizengamot that young then it would've been Dumbledore. If he did well during his time as Youth Representative then they may have offered him a permanent spot. This is mostly speculation, however.

So the data is inconclusive. We don't have any real clue as to what Dumbledore did between his sister's funeral and the events of *Fantastic Beasts*. Of course, it's likely that the films will give us more backstory on Dumbledore. All we really know is that he had become the Transfiguration teacher at Hogwarts before the events of *The Crimes of Grindelwald*, since he's shown at Hogwarts in the trailer. We know that he wasn't headmaster yet as Armando Dippet held the post during the opening of the Chamber of Secrets in 1942. There's no info that I'm aware of about who was Chief Warlock in the 1920s, or on Dumbledore's other positions and titles.